# Decimal Coordinates in the path of the URL

Tags: seo, url, url-slug

Is using decimal coordinates in a url of a page that describes the location around these coordinates a seo unfriendly decision?

For example:

```
animalobservation.com/ants/srid4326point-406206969999999998-73618128999999996
```

This is the url of my fictitious web page where I provide information about the ants living in that area of the park.

I cannot imagine a better way to distinguish that area of the park from the other one, 15 meters away, where an other species of ants live.

It is not so 'easy to read' but it is probably the most accurate choice.

Will google consider it seo unfriendly?

Is it really better to call it:

```
animalobservation.com/ants/closest-to-the-sea-part-of-the-circular-green-area-in-the-south-outer-corner-by-the-sea
```

Comment: Google will not care, it just will not help with search - that's all.

Comment: @closetnoc I am not sure about it. Couldn't we assume the same for a url that contains a barcode? However, many urls with barcodes are ranking in the top places when searching for the product they represent. I am asking the question because coordinates are far more many numbers than a barcode. Does this ring a negative bell, or the same logic could possibly apply if the content of the page is rich and relative?

Comment: Without following your logic exactly, search engines are linguistics based with some fact based knowledge in a specific ontology designed to provide factual answers. I seriously doubt that any user short of an expert will be searching for a specific bar-code (not sure how that works) or coordinate. In only that respect is it possible that a search engine can find a semantic link between the query and URL assuming that specific knowledge and recognition of the URL as coordinate data be established. This is not terribly likely without a specific ontology of coordinate data.

Comment: In short, you cannot assume that all things mean something to search engines. Your coordinates may mean something to a search engine or they may not. Either way, it does not matter at all unless humans use it to search. The URL is a major factor in search, but only as far as the search engine can recognize and understand the terms found (based upon word boundaries as recognized in a programming language).

Comment: Do what is right for your user base first and do not worry about search engines. There are other factors that are so very important to search engines that can easily override anything that a search engine cannot understand. Even if you chose to use coordinates and no-one searches, title tags, header tags, the description meta-tag, can all make the effect moot so that a search not using coordinates is still found okay. This is what is meant by my original comment. The URL, while helpful, can be made largely moot and irrelevant.

Comment: @closetnoc Thank you for the answer, I see your point! The URL friendliness counts but the page's content, the structure and the web page semantics may count even more. This is my thought too, discussing it gives more ideas. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest mistake webmasters make is trying to focus too much on SERP rankings to the deficit of the user experience. It is unlikely that a user will specifically type in a decimal coordinate to your site to access the fictitious details of ants living in that location but it is also unlikely that they will want to describe the area based on highly subjective landmark references. There are a range of situations where having the decimal coordinates of a location in the URL is very appropriate and the best option and whether you use subjective landmark based URL's or decimal based location coordinates will not affect your SERP rankings. The important thing to remember is that your URL's should make sense to someone who sees them. A website which deals with drilled down locations will make sense to use coordinates, especially if the only effective way to differentiate between locations, say two separate locations within a wide open field, is to use decimal coordinates in lieu of descriptors. As a side note this is the way that Google maps builds its URL's. The coordinates of the center point of the map are used in the URL to tell the Google Maps App where to center the map. You can imagine how unusable Google Maps could become if to center the map you needed to describe an area using words such as "100m south of the big oak tree and 200m west of the lake".